Do magnetar stars relatively produce stronger gravitational waves than neutron stars?
According to Reissner-Nordstrom solution to Einstein's gravitational field equations in astronomy the electric or magnetic or both, field of a charged body of mass generates its own gravitational field in addition to the gravitational field created by the mass of the body.
I wonder if a magnetar's enormous magnetic field would contribute to the formation of gravitational waves in relation to gravitational waves created by its mass?
In other words is it possible a magnetar of the same mass with a neutron star to produce stronger gravitational waves than the neutron star?

What's the relevance of gravitational waves? Gravitational waves propagate changes in the spacetime curvature. A static gravitational field doesn't emit gravitational waves.

But neutron stars and magnetars are known to produce gravitational waves because their rotation.

Neutron stars, especially magnetars, aren't perfectly spherically symmetrical. In fact, the intense magnetic field may make magnetars into wobbly prolate ellipsoids. See https://physics.aps.org/articles/v7/s52
